# Deleting messages from IM apps

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to do an windows phone app which deletes all conversations from Y!M messenger, Whatsapp and SMS/MMS from Message Inbox. Is there a library from sdk or some API to help me to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't intercept calls, sms, and access the isolated storage folder of another app, other than yours. The reason is security.

Comment: I just want to delete them, i don't want to use any internet protocol, just delete some local content. :(

Comment: You just can't. It's Microsoft's security policy in order to keep you phone free of malware. The exactly opposite of what happens in android.

Comment: So on Android it's possible? I mean not only for SMS inbox, also for IM's like Yahoo! Messenger or Facebook Messenger.

Comment: I know that you can intercept calls and access sms in android. For the other part of your question you should ask with the #android tag. I'm not familiar with the platform.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this. The WP8 platform does not allow communication between applications. Each application runs in its own sandbox, so the applications are isolated from each other. See this from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402533%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> Windows Phone apps run in a sandboxed process. This means that they
>   are isolated from each other, and will interact with phone features in
>   a strictly structured way. If an app needs to save data or
>   configuration information, it will do so using isolated storage, which
>   is designed to be protected from access by other apps. Apps can only
>   communicate with each other through controlled mechanisms. For more
>   information about isolated storage, see Data for Windows Phone.

Comment: that's sad, i wanted to do a Girlfriend Alert, which deletes all messages from IM apps and from SMS inbox :(

Comment: Yes, it is. It seems to me that security and usability are always in conflict.